# Slack bot - using Botkit to clear old messages

Tags: bots, slack-api, botkit

I am using botkit to develop a custom bot that will remove old messages (for example, all messages older than a week). For example, I would say '@custombot delete' while using slack. The new code that I've added to custombot.js is

```
controller.hears('delete','direct_mention',function(bot,message) {
   // customized code for removing old messages 
});
```

I've been researching Slack's API and trying to figure out how to structure this custom code. Would someone be able to point me in the direction of how I can do this?

I understand the code is along the lines of

```
bot.api.chat.delete({},function(err,response) {
   //Do something...
})
```

However I would like to target *all* messages in *every* channel that are older than a certain date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. You will have to use [channels.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history), [im.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.history), [groups.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.history) or [mpim.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/mpim.history) to retreive messages and then use [chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) individually, on each messages that you wish to delete.

You might want to look at [this Python script](https://github.com/kfei/slack-cleaner/blob/master/slack_cleaner/cli.py) to see how it's done.